# Scala Eclipse Autocomplete Broken?

Tags: eclipse, scala, autocomplete

I'm trying to get autocomplete working in eclipse for scala development. I'm trying to reference a java class from a Scala class, and the autocomplete feature never finds it.

for example take this scala class:

```
object Main {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val btn = new JButton
 }
}
```

When I hit ctrl+space at the end of typing JButton autocomplete finds "Arr", "asof", "case", "catch", "def" etc... but no classes.

in Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist->Advanced I have selected under "Default Proposal Kinds":

Java Proposals, Java Type Proposals, SWT Template Proposals and Template Proposals.

I'm using the Scala 2.8.0-final plugin under Eclipse 3.5.2, in Windows 7

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

That type of auto-completion is not yet supported by the Scala plug-in. You can get a similar result by waiting for the compile error to appear, pressing Ctrl-1, and selecting the quick fix to automatically import the type.

See the "Quick fix imports" section in this ["New and noteworthy"](http://www.scala-ide.org/2010/08/not-a-release-but-new-and-noteworthy-even-so/) post.

---

**Update September 2011:**

Luc Bourlier has [committed an improvement](http://www.assembla.com/code/scala-ide/git/changesets/75b2dd75abbe5d5760985295273261a75bf97f17) for this to give autocompletion for types on the classpath. It will be in the next beta (2.0.0-beta11), or grab a nightly build.

Answer (score 2):

The best place for questions like this is the [Scala IDE user mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user).

Answer (score 2):

here is a simple workaround: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/wiki/Known_Issues#no_completions_available

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and the solution was simple. Pick the menu option Scala -> Run Setup Diagnostics.

I clicked everything that was called "recommended", and autocomplete started working. I am pretty sure I had done this previously, but the settings might have gotten lost in an update.

[image]

Comment: Its not helpful at all. Tried with eclipse Neon.