# ScalaIDE for Eclipse: How can I autocomplete from libraries?

Tags: eclipse, scala, autocomplete

When editing Java files, if I use auto-complete on a class that hasn't yet been imported, the editor proposes the correct class and subsequently generates the import code.  When editing Scala code, the only native Java library classes appear to be supported.

Thanks to @fiction, at least I can write the name of the class and then use 'Organize Imports'(Ctrl+Shift+o) , or per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568324/scala-eclipse-autocomplete-broken/3568614#3568614) I can use quick fix to generate the import, but I'd much prefer to use autocomplete in the first place, especially if there's a question about spelling.  Is this unsupported, or is something configured something wrong?  (I've already run Setup Diagnostics with JDT content-assist checked.)

I'm using version 2.0.0.beta09-29-201107201639-529111d.

Comment: I would like to know the answer of this question, too. Also for me, seems faster to write the name of the class and then use 'Organize Imports'(Ctrl+Shift+o).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A recent message](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-ide-dev/WCenTqZCcOw/discussion) on the ScalaIDE developers forum lists a tentative "roadmap," which if I understand correctly, seems to indicate that this feature is not yet available, but should be deployed very soon (planned to be released in the next few weeks).

> 2.0 version: 1st week of September (optimistic)
>
> ...
>
> - scope completion using all types in the classpath (can be done
>     based on the Java search engine) -- probably a 'low hanging fruit'

Comment: This just landed: http://www.assembla.com/code/scala-ide/git/changesets/75b2dd75abbe5d5760985295273261a75bf97f17